# ngClass not reacting to function updating variable

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng-class

I am applying a light and dark theme using ngClass but it is not reacting to the function updating the boolean value.

When the typescript function is triggered, it prints out the correct updated value of dark_active but the class is not applied. When I update the slide toggle the classes are updating correctly.
Why does updating the value in the function not work?

```
    <div
     id="activity_row_light"
     [ngClass]="{ 'dark-theme-mode': dark_active }"
     class="row my-row report-show">
       <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="dark_active"
       ></mat-slide-toggle>....





toggleVisionMode(value: any) {
    this.darkLightMode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
    if (this.darkLightMode == 'light') {
      value = 1;    }

    if (value == 0) {
      //Dark
      localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark');
      this.dark_active = true;

    } else if (value == 1) {
      //Light
      localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light');
      this.dark_active = false;
    }
    console.log(this.dark_active)
  }
}
```

Edit:
I have discovered the issue is because I am triggering the toggleVisionMode function in the typescript file from another component. It is printing out the correct values but I cannot wrap my head around as to why its not updating the variable in the HTML

Comment: Is `dark-theme-mode` your class name?

Comment: dark-theme-mode is the class name and dark_active is the variable meant to be controlling the class

Answer (score 0):

you can try
`[ngClass]="dark-theme-mode != 1 ? 'dark_active '`

Comment: Same problem. Its not updating the classes but my slide toggle is

Comment: can u pls provide a stackblitz so i can understand the problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

`dark-theme-mode` is somewhere overridden. Use below code

```
<div id="activity_row_light" 
    [ngClass]="dark_active ? 'row my-row report-show dark-theme-mode' : 'row my-row report-show'"
    >
```

Comment: What is your this code doing ? `this.darkLightMode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
    if (this.darkLightMode == 'light') {
      value = 1;
 }` .. If you gets value = 0 passed to function and then you found 'light' in localStorage, then you prefer light only. Why this case?

Comment: Same issue. Updating the variable through my function is not affecting the class but the slide toggle is